# Why does my HTC desire mount the SD card in read only mode?

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd

I have a new HTC desire. After 3 days of use it started mounting the SD card in read only mode. I couldn't mount it in read-write mode until I formated the card in another phone.

I read somewhere on the HTC forums that this may be caused by plugging the phone in a Mac. But this doesn't make any sense to me. I did plug the phone in a Mac the first time, but this didn't start happening after that. It started happening after I've plugged the phone in a Windows 7 pc. I've never used the phone plugged in a computer in sync mode, it was either used as a mass storage device or in charge only mode (which was the case before this problem ocured). Of all the portable devices I've used that could be used as a mass storage there's never been a problem if I've used them with OS X, Linux or Windows. So I don't find the OS X explanation satisfactory. From what I know all operating systems will handle mass storage devices in the same way more or less especially if it's a FAT filesystem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: What software version do you have? When I first had my Desire I occasionally found my SD Card was read-only, though this was fixed with a reboot and did not require reformatting. At some point, one update or another must have fixed the issue as I haven't seen it for some time - certainly not since updating to Froyo/2.2.

Comment: I had a lot of SD card issues with my Desire. Sometimes read only but more often failed to mount it completely, and I've heard a few similar tales. I ended up having it replaced on warranty (because it was overheating and restarting) and have had no SD card problems at all with the replacement.

Comment: @FoleyIsGood It's Froyo. I haven't had that problem in the past few weeks but I haven't connected it to a computer via USB in that time either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with stock 2.1 ROM.

After the OTA update to 2.2, the problem vanished.

Answer (score 1):

I have HTC Desire too. I don't know what causes this problem, but I fixed it by mounting it on a Windows computer and checking the filesystem on the card. I tried it on a Mac first, but OSX Disk Utility couldn't fix the problems it found.